# docx to PDF using reportlab without using application

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx, reportlab

Is there a way to convert a .docx to .pdf using reportlab?

I have this code but I don't find a way to achieve the addition of each page to `canvas.Canvas()`, to convert to a pdf without using an external application. I want to add into the canvas each page of the document, like a copy paste or like a screenshot to convert to an image and add it to the canvas.

I'm looking for a way without MS Office applications to convert a `.docx` file into a `.pdf` using reportlab, converting each page of the .docx file into images or an object that `reportlab` accepts, in order to convert without disturbing the format.

Here is my code:

````
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image   #   pip install pillow
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas #   pip install reportlab

documentStream = Document(BytesIO(WordStream.getvalue()))
seccion = documentStream.sections[0]
height = seccion.page_height
width = seccion.page_width

application = BytesIO()
documentStream.save(application)
application.seek(0)
canva = canvas.Canvas(application)
canva.setPageSize((round(width.pt), round(height.pt)))

canva.showPage()
canva.save()
application.seek(0)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Extract the content from the .docx file, including text and images.
Convert each page (containing text and images) into an image.
Create a PDF and add each image to it using reportlab.
Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from docx import Document
from PIL import Image
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

# Load the .docx file
docx_path = 'your_document.docx'
doc = Document(docx_path)

# Create a PDF file
pdf_output = BytesIO()
pdf_canvas = canvas.Canvas(pdf_output, pagesize=letter)

# Iterate through each page of the .docx document
for page in doc.element.body:
    # Create a PIL Image of the page content
    page_image = Image.new("RGB", (792, 612), "white")  # Use the appropriate dimensions
    page_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(page_image)

    # Extract and draw text and images onto the image
    for element in page:
        if element.tag.endswith('t'):  # Text
            text = element.text
            # Draw text on the page_image using page_draw
            # You may need to handle formatting and positioning
        elif element.tag.endswith('blip'):  # Image
            image_data = element.get_or_add_image()._blob
            image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data))
            # Draw the image on the page_image using page_draw
            # You may need to handle image positioning and sizing

    # Add the page_image to the PDF
    pdf_canvas.drawImage(page_image, 0, 0, width=letter[0], height=letter[1])
    pdf_canvas.showPage()

# Save the PDF file
pdf_output.seek(0)
with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(pdf_output.read())

pdf_output.close()
```

This code extracts text and images from each page of the .docx document, creates an image of the page content, and then adds that image to a PDF using reportlab. You will need to customize the code to handle the positioning, formatting, and sizing of text and images to match your specific .docx file's structure.

Please note that this approach may not perfectly preserve the formatting of complex documents, and you might need to further fine-tune the code to handle different types of content in your .docx file.

**or**

Converting a .docx file to a .pdf without using the python-docx library is a more complex task because you need to parse the .docx file format and handle various elements like text, images, tables, and formatting manually.

You can use a third-party library like mammoth to convert .docx to HTML and then use reportlab to create a PDF from that HTML. Here's an example using these libraries:

```
from io import BytesIO
import mammoth
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Load the .docx file and convert it to HTML
docx_path = 'your_document.docx'
with open(docx_path, 'rb') as docx_file:
    result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file)

html_content = result.value

# Create a PDF file
pdf_output = BytesIO()
pdf_doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_output, pagesize=letter)

# Define styles for the PDF
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
normal_style = styles['Normal']

# Parse HTML and add it to the PDF
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
pdf_content = []

for tag in soup.find_all():
    text = tag.get_text()
    if tag.name == 'p':
        pdf_content.append(Paragraph(text, normal_style))
    elif tag.name == 'ul':
        # Handle unordered lists if needed
        pass
    elif tag.name == 'ol':
        # Handle ordered lists if needed
        pass

pdf_doc.build(pdf_content)

# Save the PDF file
pdf_output.seek(0)
with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(pdf_output.read())

pdf_output.close()
```

In this code:

It uses the mammoth library to convert the .docx file to HTML.
It parses the HTML and extracts text content and any other elements you want to handle (e.g., lists).
It uses reportlab to create a PDF from the extracted HTML content.
Please note that this approach may not handle all formatting and complex document structures perfectly, but it can be a reasonable solution for simpler .docx documents. Complex documents with advanced formatting may require more specialized tools or manual adjustment of the generated HTML content before converting it to PDF.